# Energy of the charge distribution in the linear dielectric medium

Tags: electrostatics, dielectric

While reading *Introduction to Electrodynamics* by David J. Griffiths, I have encountered some troubles in understanding the energy in the dielectric system. Without the dielectric,  we considered the work required to assemble the spatial configuration of charges (firstly we bring the first charge from infinity to its final position, then the second and so on) which yielded (in the discrete case):

$$W=\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}q_{i}\varphi(\mathbf{r}_{i})$$

Where $\varphi$ is the electric potential. In the case of the continuous charge distribution within the volume $V$:

$$W=\frac{1}{2}\int\limits_{V}\rho(\mathbf{r})\varphi(\mathbf{r})dV$$

Then we could use Gauss theorem $\rho=\epsilon_0 \nabla\cdot\mathbf{E}$ and integration by parts to arrive at:

$$W=\frac{\epsilon_0}{2}\left(\int\limits_{V}E^2 dV+\oint\limits_{\partial V}\varphi\mathbf{E}\cdot d\mathbf{A}\right)$$

If the charge distribution is confined to some finite volume, the flux integral will drop to 0 when we increase the region of integration to cover all space (apparently we can do that because from the first equation we presume that the regions where $\rho=0$ will not contribute to the value of the integral). Then we arrive at:

$$W=\frac{\epsilon_0}{2}\int\limits_{\text{all space}}E^2 dV$$.

Now my question is, can we devise the same lovely picture (bringing the charges to their final positions) when we deal with dielectric material. For example, if we have the system of the dielectric with some embedded free charges, can we speak of the work done to "assemble" the system? How do we account for the fact that some of the energy is stored in the polarized molecules of the dielectric assuming that initially we are given an unpolarized dielectric material (for simplicity let's deal with LIH dielectrics).